# Relaying the status of a 2D-Array in a loop

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, do-while

Because my code is kinda long and I heard we're allowed to ask questions as long it fulfills a certain criteria in this forum, I've uploaded my [code into Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KizeSvfEpioGd3DKVzXc5_bgcBgt1v2Y/view).

To put my issue into words, assuming that the first loop is completed after the `compare` function is executed in my `main`, `while` loops a part of my main because `currentprogress[x][y]!=finalpuzzle[x][y]` in `compare` function; when the second loop is performed, the option chosen by the user does not stay in the `currentprogress` 2D-Array and hence no matter how many times an input is recorded at variable `choice` in `currentprogress` function , the program will not proceed.

How do I relay the status of a 2D Array from the first loop to the second and so on?

Thank you!

Comment: I didn't follow the link but: whatever you might have heard - IMHO, better forget it. Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you are not able to reproduce your issue in a small example which fits into the question text then this is the wrong platform for your question.

Comment: You are passing `stat` by value to `compare`, so the function modify a copy of that variable. Change the signature to either pass a pointer or simply return that value: `stat = compare(temp, store);`. I haven't read the rest of your code, it's too long.

Comment: @Scheff, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

in your `main()` I noticed that there is the key word `do` but never the `while`, which prevents you from buckling.

Then, to be able to recover the value of `state`, there are two solutions. The first is to return the value of your `state` variable,

```
char compare(char currentprogress[NROW][NCOL], char finalpuzzle[NROW][NCOL], char status) {
  // Your code
  return (status); 
}
```

and the second is to pass the pointer parameter to access the same memory area as the variable of your "main".

```
void compare(char currentprogress[NROW][NCOL], char finalpuzzle[NROW][NCOL], char *status){
    *status = 'f'; // now your state variable has the same value in your main()
}
```

To understand this mechanism I advise you to reseign on the scopes, and sends the parameter by copy. In other words, the variable `state` in `compare` has the same value as the one in your `main` when you send it, but it's not the same, it's a copy.